PyQt5 Splitting One Large Widget into Multiple Smaller Widgets
I am having a hard time trying to understand how to break one large widget into multiple smaller nested widgets to make my widgets more portable. I am having difficulty getting things to display from the nested widgets. I have something like this:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
import PyQt5.QtGui
import PIL.ImageTk
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
import picamera2

class CameraWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CameraWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.camera1 = picamera2.Picamera2(0)
        self.camera1.configure(self.camera1.create_preview_configuration(main={"size": (640, 480)}))
        self.camera1.start()

        self.camera2 = picamera2.Picamera2(1)
        self.camera2.configure(self.camera2.create_preview_configuration(main={"size": (640, 480)}))
        self.camera2.start()

        self.cam1_view = QLabel()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.cam1_view)

        self.cam2_view = QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.cam2_view)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_frame)
        self.timer.start(int(1000 / 24))

    def update_frame(self):
        image = self.camera1.capture_image()
        image = image.convert("RGBA")
        data = image.tobytes("raw", "RGBA")
        qim = ImageQt(image)
        pix = PyQt5.QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
        self.cam1_view.setPixmap(pix)

        image = self.camera2.capture_image()
        image = image.convert("RGBA")
        data = image.tobytes("raw", "RGBA")
        qim = ImageQt(image)
        pix = PyQt5.QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
        self.cam2_view.setPixmap(pix)

        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Raspberry Pi Camera Viewer")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1280, 480)

        self.central_widget = CameraWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

But as you can see the CameraWidget has two cameras inside, which I would like to make a single camera with another class containing 2 CameraWidgets. I tried splitting them in the following way but nothing is displaying:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
import PyQt5.QtGui
import PIL.ImageTk
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
import picamera2

class CameraWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, cameraId=0):
        super(MyCamera, self).__init__(parent)

        self.camera = picamera2.Picamera2(cameraId)
        self.camera.configure(self.camera.create_preview_configuration(main={"size": (640, 480)}))
        self.camera.start()

        self.cam_view = QLabel()

    def update_frame(self):
        image = self.camera.capture_image()
        image = image.convert("RGBA")
        data = image.tobytes("raw", "RGBA")
        qim = ImageQt(image)
        pix = PyQt5.QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
        self.cam_view.setPixmap(pix)

class CamerasWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyCameras, self).__init__(parent)

        self.cam1 = CameraWidget()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.cam1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_frames)
        self.timer.start(int(1000 / 24))
    
    def update_frames(self):
        self.cam1.update_frame()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Raspberry Pi Camera Viewer")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1280, 480)

        self.central_widget = CamerasWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

The app with the cameras split displays nothing on the window. Can someone help me make these nested classes?

The further QLabel is pointless and is never shown nor added to a layout. Just subclass from QLabel instead of QWidget, and replace self.cam_view with self.
